# Is proving this with Taylor is true?

Tags: functions

Prove for every $x \neq 0$ in the domain $(-1, \infty )$ that:

$$ln(1+x) < x $$

My prove:

$$ln(1+x) < x  \iff $$-$$ e^{ln(1+x)} < e^x \iff $$-$$ 1+x < e^x  $$
and since  Taylor's series of $e^x$ is : $$ e^x = 1+x + R_n2(x) $$
$$R_n2(x)= \frac{e^c}{2}x^2 >0 $$ 
$$\implies 1+x+R_n2(x) > 1+x $$

is this okay?

Comment: Well, why is $R_n(x) > 0$? (also, I reckon the most direct way to prove this is by concavity of $f\colon x\in (-1,\infty)\mapsto \ln(1+x)$, which ensures that $f(x) \leq f(0) + f^\prime(0) x$.)

Comment: @ClementC. It's bigger than 0 only in $(0, \infty ) $ right?

Comment: No, it's actually non-negative everywhere. But it is only obvious on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @ClementC.  I proved it by concavity but I want to know if what I did was right? and I edited my answer for $R_n(x)$ .. can you check it for me/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your (original) proof doesn't really concerns the case when $-1<x<0$, because in that case the remainder might be negative. Actually the remainder is nonnegative, which can indeed be proved with the Lagrange remainder.

You can consider, instead, the function $f(x)=x-\ln(1+x)$; its derivative is
$$
f'(x)=1-\frac{1}{1+x}=\frac{x}{1+x}
$$
that only vanishes at $0$; prove $0$ is a point of minimum and use the fact that $f(0)=0$.

With the same argument applied to $g(x)=e^x-1-x$, that has $g'(x)=e^x-1$, so a minimum at $0$, you prove that $e^x\ge 1+x$ for all real $x$.

Comment: ahh, then $f(x) < 0 $ for every $x \neq 0, (-1,\infty) $ $\implies ln(1+x) -x <0 $

Comment: But the remainder is bigger than zero for every $x$, I proved it up there..
If you choose Lagrange remainder

Comment: @SijaanHallak Well, yes, but your first version didn't have that. However, I find this proof much simpler.

Comment: I agree.. Thanks!